# disfunctional jekyll theme for GitHub project page blog --> gh-pages

Tags: github, pagination, themes, jekyll, blogs

When I use a dedicated GitHub page to host this blog the theme works, see [here](https://description-logicians-of-eis.github.io/).

However, what I want to do is create this blog as a "Project Page", i.e. a subpage of an organization, in [this way](http://eis-bonn.github.io/Description-Logicians-of-EIS/).

I've been following the tutorial on how to create a gh-pages branch, [provided by GitHub themselves](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually/).

In conjunction with the "[Host on GitHub in 3 Minutes](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/usage/jekyll-quick-start.html)" tutorial from Jekyll.

I can get it up and running with the basic out-of-the-box theme, but I want to use the "[twitter theme](http://themes.jekyllbootstrap.com/)", but when I followed the command to install it, i.e. `rake theme:install git="https://github.com/jekyllbootstrap/theme-twitter.git"` and then pushed to the gh-pages branch, it just completely stripped away all the formatting and now there is no theme at all, see [here](http://eis-bonn.github.io/Description-Logicians-of-EIS/).

Why did that happen? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual it's a `baseurl` problem. In _config.yml : set

`baseurl: /Description-Logicians-of-EIS`

or `BASE_PATH` if you use Jekyll Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

If you open up the console in your browser (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>), you can see the CSS fails to load with a 404.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://eis-bonn.github.io/assets/themes/twitter/css/1.4.0/bootstrap.css
```

That's probably a good starting point. Where are your css files stored?

#### Spoiler Alert!

When I visit [your repository](https://github.com/EIS-Bonn/eis-bonn.github.com), the directory pointed to in your header is missing. Instead I find Bootstrap in an [entirely different directory](https://github.com/EIS-Bonn/eis-bonn.github.com/tree/master/assets/themes/bootstrap-3/bootstrap/css).